# Overlay image in Mapbox gl doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to prepare image overlay layer in mapbox gl with city plan as background. It works perfect in Firefox but in Chrome I see only dark grey polygon. I use 4Mb .png file.

Firefox Desktop - ok

Firefox Mobile- not ok

Chrome Deskotop -not ok

Firefox Mobile -not ok
[image]

```
       map.addLayer({
                "id": "overlay",
                "source": {
                    "type": "image",
                    "url": "7.png",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [30.0112567, 51.4361221],
                        [30.187844, 51.4361221],
                        [30.187844, 51.3696605],
                        [30.0112567, 51.3696605]
                    ]
                },
                "type": "raster",
                "paint": {
                    "raster-opacity": 0.85
                }
            });
```